# change div content when click on link with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a jplayer musicplayer with a playlist that works as it should and now I would like to be able to change the first myPlaylist1 to myPlaylist2 when click on a link.

The function that loads the first playlist- myPlaylist1 into the div #theplayer looks like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var description = 'Some description. ';

    $('#theplayer').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist1, {
        autoPlay:false, 
        description:description,
        currencySymbol:'Kr ',
        buyText:'K&Ouml;P',
        tracksToShow:50,
        jPlayer:{
            swfPath:'http://www.mypage.com/music_player/jquery-jplayer' //You need to override the default swf path any time the directory structure changes
        }
    });
```

When I click on a link I would like to change the above to myPlaylist2 below:

```
    $('#theplayer').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist2, {
        autoPlay:false, 
        description:description,
        currencySymbol:'Kr ',
        buyText:'K&Ouml;P',
        tracksToShow:50, 
        jPlayer:{
            swfPath:'http://www.mypage.com/music_player/jquery-jplayer' //You need to override the default swf path any time the directory structure changes
        }
    });
```

And with this I hope that playlist2 will be displayed instead of playlist1?

The playlists that loads when the page loads looks like this:

```
var myPlaylist1 = [
    {
        mp3:'http://www.www.mypage.com/music_player/mix/1.mp3',
        title:'Love The Way You Lie',
        artist:'Eminem',
        buy:'#',
        price:'12',
        cover:'http://www.mypage.com/music_player/images/1.jpg'
     }  
];
```

And when click on the link I like to change the playlist to this instead.

```
    var myPlaylist2 = [
        {
            mp3:'http://www.www.mypage.com/music_player/mix/2.mp3',
            title:'Hey you',
            artist:'Madonna',
            buy:'#',
            price:'12',
            cover:'http://www.mypage.com/music_player/images/2.jpg'
         }  


];
```

Or if you have any other suggestion on how to change the playlists?

Any input really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

create a link with an id called "pl_changer"

and the following should do as you ask:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pl_changer").click(function(){
    $('#theplayer').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist2, {
        autoPlay:false, 
        description:description,
        currencySymbol:'Kr ',
        buyText:'K&Ouml;P',
        tracksToShow:50, 
        jPlayer:{
            swfPath:'http://www.mypage.com/music_player/jquery-jplayer' //You need to override the default swf path any time the directory structure changes
        }
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks tehlulz, I added an alert after the .click(function to see if it runs and it shows the alert, but it doesnt change the playlist Im afraid.